# UIImagePickerController going to a white screen after the takePicture method is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to program a `UIImagePickerController` with a custom `cameraOverlayView`. When I call the `takePicture` method of my `UIImagePickerController`, the `UIView` changes to a white screen instead of the picker where you can select "Use Photo". How can I set the subsequent `UIView` to be the picker instead of a blank `UIView`?

I have included my code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)dealloc
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{




//Start the camera up

_imageViewPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

//Hide default UI elements

_imageViewPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
_imageViewPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
_imageViewPickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
_imageViewPickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

//Start the button overlay

UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_imageViewPickerController.view.bounds];
btnView.opaque = NO;
btnView.clipsToBounds = YES;

//Start up the button
UIButton *snapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-6, 504, 65, 65)];
snapButton.alpha = 0.5;
snapButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(90));
[snapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(snapThat) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//Set the button's picture
UIImage *snapButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];
[snapButton setImage:snapButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Add button to the overlay
[btnView addSubview:snapButton];

//Overlay button view

_imageViewPickerController.cameraOverlayView = btnView;

//Fix for iPhone 5 and make fullscreen

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -55.0);
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.333333, 1.333333);
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(180));
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate);
_imageViewPickerController.cameraViewTransform = transform;

//Let's present it all

[self presentViewController:_imageViewPickerController
                   animated:NO
                 completion:NULL];


}

- (void)snapThat {
[_imageViewPickerController takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
// Save photo
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
}
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

EDIT: I've modified my code to include this, and I still get the blank UIView:
    `[self presentViewController:_imageViewPickerController
                       animated:NO
                     completion:NULL];`
Shouldn't this save the picture and return me to the camera view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I call the takePicture method of my UIImagePickerController, the UIView changes to a white screen instead of the picker where you can select "Use Photo".

It's doing that because *you* are calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` implementation. If you don't want the camera interface to be dismissed, don't dismiss it.

You do not get any automatic second view (where you can select "Use Photo" or whatever). If you want that, you must create your own second view controller and push it onto the UIImagePickerController (which is a navigation controller).

Comment: I explain more about this here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch30.html#_using_the_camera

Comment: And here's a downloadable example where I create a second view controller and push it onto the UIImagePickerController so the user can decide whether to use this image or not: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p704takeAPicture2/ch30p962takeAPicture2/ViewController.m

Comment: I've modified the OP in regards to my question. It seems like my code should all work. If you wouldn't mind clarifying further I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've explained in my answer what to do, I've pointed you to some working code that you can download and run, and I've written a discussion (at the end of this section of my book, http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch30.html#_using_the_camera) of what that code is doing. I really don't see what more you can want.